# calculating age from date of birth using hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to calculate age from given user date of birth.
how can i do it ? is there any specific command available in hive?
Not finding much on it. I tried with DATEDIFF but not getting proper output its giving only null

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, user_dob, unix_timestamp()) / 365.25)
```

Comment: What results are you getting?  You look like you're on roughly the right track.  Also what is the format of user_dob?  Perhaps it isn't being converting to a date correctly

Comment: 2/14/1993  12:00:00 AM this is how my DOB looks like

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select 
   floor(datediff(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), 
   to_date(cust_brth_day)) / 365.25) 
from some_table;
```

Answer (score 3):

Current year minus birth year
plus if their birth month is greater than current month -1
plus if their birth month is equal to current month 
and birth day of month is greater than current day of month -1

```
select birth_date
, current_year
, (year(current_date) - year(birth_date) 
   +case when month(birth_date) > month(current_date) then -1
         when month(birth_date) = month(current_date) and day(birth_date) > day(current_date) then -1
         else 0 
     end) as age
from person
```